# What is the formal definition of the set $E^n$?

Tags: general-topology, notation, nonlinear-optimization

I'm currently in a non-linear optimization course, and I can't seem to find, even in the book, the definition of $E^n$, which is clearly some set. Please see the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW7Iq.png) below context.

Comment: At a guess, it just means $\mathbb R^n$ with the standard Euclidean norm.  But I expect they define the term early on in the text.

Comment: It is Euclidean space of  dimension $n,$ with the usual vector length given by square root of the dot product with itself

Comment: I have no idea. I assume that is defined in earlier chapters.  If it was $\mathbb{R}^n$ it would make more sense.  Funny writing a whole chapter that uses $E^n$ and not bothering to give the half-sentence definition of it!

Comment: Ah, seeing as the Euclidian norm comes into play pretty often, this makes sense. Many thanks!

Comment: Note that "unit disk" in German is "Einheitskreis", and you will see $E^n$ for it in many books, like Spanier's *Algebraic Topology*.

Comment: Advanced Calculus by Devinatz uses $E$ for the set of real numbers instead of the more common $\Bbb R$ or $R$.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{E}^n$ is used to denote Euclidean $n$-space, that is $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the Euclidean norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^+$, $ \Vert\textbf{x}\Vert=\sqrt{\textbf{x}\cdot\textbf{x}}$, and distance function $d(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})=\Vert\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}\Vert$

The notation $\textbf{E}^n$ is used to distinguish a Euclidean space from a non-Euclidean real spaces. For example, $\textbf{H}^n$ is used to denote a real hyperbolic space, which may be constructed from $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ with the distance function $d(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})=\text{arcosh}{B(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})}$.

Comment: What's your B??

Comment: @ArcticChar It depends on $n$, a decent explanation can be found in the "models of hyperbolic space" section of the Wikipedia article on hyperbolic space, but you might write it as $x_0y_0-\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i$

Answer (score -1):

A set is a well-defined collection of distinct objects. ... The most basic properties are that a set can have elements and that two sets are equal (one and the same) if and only if every element of each set is an element of the other; this property is called the extensionality of sets.

Comment: I think you may have posted this in the wrong place, because it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question. Can you clarify?